# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on each js file that invoked in the index html

Tags: javascript, mean-stack

I am using mean stack to build a website, when testing, chrome returns the error like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <   angular.js:1.

I don't know what's wrong and what should i do.

[image]

Here is the directory of my app:
`E-study
  -client
   -app
   -components
    -all the libraries are here.
   -index.html
   -controllers.js
  -node_modules
  -server
   -config
    -server.js`

And I run the server in E-study like :`node server/config/server.js`

The scripts in the index.html is`<script src="client/components/angular/angular.js"></script>`

Just don't know why all the js files are changed to index.html when open in the browser.

Comment: Well it means that those files aren't valid JS, but likely HTML instead. Maybe an error message. Fix your server.

Comment: yeah, all the JS file has been changed to index html when open in the browser, don't know why.

Comment: because you are not providing the correct path..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

open up those library files and see if there are some extra symbol `<` probably you will find it in the beginning.. if still not able to fix... simply download the fresh library (if those are libraries) from the internet and try again.

make sure that you don't put `<script> </script>` tags in the included `.js` files. that is an incorrect syntax for script files.

also make sure you are providing the correct path??? providing incorrect path can return a builtin customized error page. which is html. may be that is the source of error because returned page is HTML which is most likely going to start with a < symbol. and offcourse not a js file.

to ensure that the incorrect path is the issue just copy the path you included in the code and and paste into your favorite browsers url bar and hit enter. if you are not getting the script in plain text.. then it means you are not providing the correct path.

and if it is return a customized error page like .. 404 not found  then probably it is returning the html and this is where the error is coming from.

Comment: I have downloaded all the library again but still the same problem.

Comment: did you opened up the library and saw anything inside it???
and could you provide the link from where you downloaded that js library!!!

Comment: are you providing the correct path??? providing incorrect path can return a builtin customized error page. which is html. may be that is the source of error

Comment: then instead of using <script src="client/components/angular/angular.js"> 
use <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>

Comment: the index file is in folder client, it is in the same level of components.

Comment: then instead of using <script src="client/components/angular/angular.js"> use <script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>

or use 
 
<script src="./components/angular/angular.js"></script>

Comment: under which server you are running the html??? or running directly via providing path

Comment: I am using express server, at port 8080, all the js files are downloaded through npm in terminal.

Comment: what path you are putting in the addressbar.. to access that index.html

Comment: and rewrite the app.use（express.static(...)）

Comment: @ Sanjeev Prasad Thakur   I have another problem, can you help me to solve it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440099/mean-angular-ui-router-doesnt-load-states/41440173?noredirect=1#comment70086612_41440173

Comment: @vivian can you send an example if your code? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

In external `js` files, which you refer in some other files, **don't use** `<script>..</script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For express server try to set the static path to entire project folder.It worked for me

**app.use(express.static(__dirname ));**

Answer (score 0):

Could be a ReCaptcha bot checker type thing intercepting requests for JS files and serving up an HTML page instead, which is invalid HTML so it throws the < is invalid message error.

I know siteground specifically has issues with this intercepting CDN routed traffic.

Check with the host to remove this issue, in this case it's their anti-bot security setup.  This has remedied these issues with Siteground for me.